# XAMPP Control Panel not appearing in start menu

Tags: xampp

I just installed XAMPP 7.3.5 on a Windows 10 machine.  The XAMPP Control Panel is not showing up in the start menu though.  An older installation of XAMPP on a Windows 7 machine displays the XAMPP Control Panel in the start menu, as shown by the screenshot below.  How do I get XAMPP Control Panel to show up in the start menu in Windows 10?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows go to `C:\xampp`, find the xampp-control application, right-click with the mouse button and click "Pin to start".

[image: Adding xampp-control panel to start menu]

Answer (score 1):

This is for Windows 10 and it should work for any other program you want to appear in the start menu:

1. Right-click xampp-control.exe (in your XAMPP installation directory)
2. Select "create shortcut"
3. Cut and paste shortcut to C:\Users[your username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs

Apparently the XAMPP installer either doesn't ask to be added to the start menu or I skipped over the option in haste! Now the XAMPP control panel appears when I start typing in the start menu, which is what I want for my workflow.